# test if number is in string in R

Tags: r, sql-like

I have the following df

```
df <-
    a    b  c
    20  10 20€
    20€ 10 20 Euro
```

I want to test if the number 20 is part of a field. Result should therefore looks like this:

```
[1]true [2]false [3]true
[4]true [5]false [6]true
```

I tried

```
grepl(df[3,3], 20)
grepl(df[3,3], "20")
```

Both of which return false.

Comment: You've just got your arguments in the wrong order. For `grepl`, it's pattern first, then data. `grepl("20", df$a)`

Comment: If you have a `tidyverse` inclination, you could use `matrix(readr::parse_number(as.matrix(df)) == 20, dim(df))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said you wanted a matrix-like view of logicals. Brian's comment is correct, the pattern comes first ... but you also need to account for the structure: `grepl(ptn, some_data_frame)` returns a vector (looks like an "all-or-nothing" per-column), while `grepl(ptn, some_matrix)` returns a logical for every element in the matrix ... albeit not with the correct dimensions, correctable.

```r
`dim<-`(grepl("20", as.matrix(df)), dim(df))
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
# [1,] TRUE FALSE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE FALSE TRUE

### or, more eye-friendly
out <- grepl("20", as.matrix(df))
dim(out) <- dim(df)
out
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3]
# [1,] TRUE FALSE TRUE
# [2,] TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

BTW: if you are looking for *any number including "20"*, to include 120 and 200, then this is fine. If you want fields where the only number component is "20" (neither 120 nor 200 count), then you need `"\\b20\\b"` as your pattern. (Thanks Andrew.)

---

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(header=T, text="
    a    b  c
    20  10 20€
    20€ 10 20Euro")
```

---

BTW: the reason that `grepl("20", df)` returns a vector of length 3 (one for each column) is that internally it is converting the object to character. This explains why you only get three:

```r
as.character(df)
# [1] "c(20, 20)" "c(10, 10)" "1:2"
```

Comment: It may be safer to surround `"20"` with word boundaries: `"\\b20\\b"`. Although, OP doesn't have values like `120` or `200` in the example that would partially match, so I am just assuming they do not want partial matches.

Comment: Good point, I'll leave it to the OP to determine that. (I agree, btw.)

Comment: Eh, I just realized that the word boundary would knock out `20Euro` so it wasn't a great suggestion here. OP would need lookarounds if they really wanted to only match `20` using regex. Proabbly not helpful to speculate at this point but I think this would do it: `"(?<!\\d)20(?!\\d)"`. Great answer btw, learned how to use  ``dim<-``.

Comment: I actually *dislike* using assignment-functions inline like that, but to me it highlights the fact that the original function could use better behavior (perhaps `grepl(ptn, mtx)` could return a matrix instead of a vector? \*shrug\*)

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to use `Vectorize` function over here or may be `purrr::map_dfr`

```
Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = 'x')(pattern='20', df)
purrr::map_dfr(df, ~grepl('20', .x))
```

But my solution is not better than the above one(@r2evans has  more elegant), In case you want to match strictly 20, then you can also use boundary conditions `\\b20\\b` instead of just `20`.

**data**:

```
structure(list(a = c("20", "20€"), b = c("10", "10"), c = c("20€", 
"2 Euro")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

**Output**:

```
Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = 'x')(pattern='20', df)
        a     b     c
[1,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```